# Proving the set of distances is connected

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let A be a connected subset of a metric space X and let $y \in X$. Let $E\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be defined as $E=\{d(a,y):a\in A\}$. Show that E is connected.

This is what I got so far:

Assume E is not connected, then E is not an interval. Thus $\exists a_1,a_2 \in A$ and $  t\in \mathbb{R}, t\notin A $ such that $d(a_1,y)<t<d(a_2,y)$. I'm not sure how to continue, any suggestions/hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $U=\{x \in A: d(x,y) <t\}$ and $V=\{x \in A: d(x,y) >t\}$. These are disjoint and their union is $A$ because $t$ does not belong to $E$. I leave it yo you to verify that these two sets are open. Since $a_1 \in U$ and $a_2 \in V$ these two sets are nonempty, contradicting the fact that $A$ is connected. Hint for showing that $U$ is open: let $d(x_0,y) <t$. Verify that $B(x_0,r) \subset U$ if $0<r<t-d(x_0,y)$.

Answer (score 0):

$\textbf{Hint}$
What can we say about the image of a connected set under a continuous map?

Comment: We haven't talked about continuous mappings in the context of connected sets. We talked about the following proposit ions: 
1- E is disconnected iff $E=U1 \cup U2$ where U1 and U2 are nonempty disjoint open subsets of X 
2- E is connected iff the only clopen sets are E and the empty set

Comment: I'll just tell you what happens in that case then, and hopefully it helps with your proof. Suppose $f:X\to Y$ is a continuous map from a connect set to any topological space. Suppose $U,V\subseteq f(X)$ are disjoint open sets, and $U\cup V=f(X)$. Then we know that $f^{-1}(U),f^{-1}(V)$ are open, disjoint, and their union is $X$. This gives us that $f^{-1}(V)=\emptyset$ or $f^{-1}(U)=\emptyset$, hence $U=\emptyset$ or $V=\emptyset$, therefore $f(X)$ is connected.